# How to overcome image distortion on smaller screens (576px) in a Bootstrap 5 responsive design?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, bootstrap-5

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8xg99.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XYMWs.png)

```html
    <div class="banner">

    </div>
```

```
.banner {
    background-image: url(../img/portada.png);
    height: 20rem;                                 /* Doy altura porque esta vacio*/
    background-size: cover;                        /* Llena todo el espacio disponible */
    background-position: center center;            /* Crece la imagen desde el centro */
}
```

```
@media screen and (max-width: 576px) {
  
  

  .banner{
    width:100%;
  }
```

Alguien sabe porque se me queda la imagen como en la foto al ser la pantalla mas pequeña de 576px y sabe como solucionarlo?

Comment: background-size: contain; - But.... you're whole approach is flawed I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

`background-size: cover` ensures that the background is covered, but does *not* ensure that the full image is displayed. This is why you only see part of it on smaller screens.

Try changing it to `background-size: contain` to ensure that the full image is shown regardless.